# onPostExecute(JSONObject json) is not executed

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

I have a register fragment that should send the registration details to a database. The data is succesfully sent by the fragment. However, the progress dialog is not dismissing. I suspected onPostExecute(JSONObject json) is not executed. If the json tag success:1 the progress dialog should dismiss.

Register Fragment

```
public class RegisterFragment extends Fragment {

public RegisterFragment(){}

/**
 *  JSON Response node names.
 **/
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_ADDRESS1 = "address1";
private static String KEY_ADDRESS2 = "address2";
private static String KEY_CITY = "city";
private static String KEY_STATE = "state";
private static String KEY_POSTAL = "postal";
private static String KEY_COUNTRY = "country";
private static String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";

/**
 * Defining layout items.
 **/
EditText inputFirstName;
EditText inputLastName;
EditText inputUsername;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
EditText inputAddress1;
EditText inputAddress2;
EditText inputCity;
EditText inputState;
EditText inputpostal;
EditText inputCountry;
EditText inputPhone;
Button btnRegister;
TextView registerErrorMsg;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);
    /**
     * Defining all layout items
     **/
    inputFirstName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fname);
    inputLastName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lname);
    inputUsername = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.uname);
    inputEmail = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pword);
    inputAddress1 =(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.regAddress1);
    inputAddress2 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.regAddress2);
    inputCity = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.regCity);
    inputState = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.regState);
    inputpostal = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.regPostal);
    inputCountry = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.regCountry);
    inputPhone = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.regPhone);
    btnRegister = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.register);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.register_error);

    /**
     * Button which Switches back to the login screen on clicked
     **/

            Button login = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bktologin);
            login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    mFragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE); 
                    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, new LoginFragment(), "Back To Login");
                    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
                }

            });

       /**
       * Register Button click event.
       * A Toast is set to alert when the fields are empty.
       * Another toast is set to alert Username must be 5 characters.
       **/

            btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (  ( !inputUsername.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputFirstName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputLastName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                    {
                        if ( inputUsername.getText().toString().length() > 4 ){
                            NetAsync(view);

                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Username should be minimum 5 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                "One or more fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });             

    return rootView;
}

/**
 * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working
 **/

private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
{
    private ProgressDialog nDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterFragment.this.getActivity());
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){


/**
 * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
 **/
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                urlc.connect();
                if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

        if(th == true){
            nDialog.dismiss();
            new ProcessRegister().execute();
        }
        else{
            nDialog.dismiss();
            registerErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
            Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Error in Network Connection";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}

private class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    /**
     * Defining Process dialog
     **/
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    String email,password,fname,lname,uname, address1, address2,
    city, state, postal, country, phone;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        fname = inputFirstName.getText().toString();
        lname = inputLastName.getText().toString();
        email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
        uname= inputUsername.getText().toString();
        password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        address1 = inputAddress1.getText().toString();
        address2 = inputAddress2.getText().toString();
        city = inputCity.getText().toString();
        state = inputState.getText().toString();
        postal = inputpostal.getText().toString();
        country = inputCountry.getText().toString();
        phone = inputPhone.getText().toString();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterFragment.this.getActivity());
        pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Register user on the database
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(fname, lname, email, uname, password, address1, address2,
                city, state, postal, country, phone);
        return json;
    }

   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
       super.onPostExecute(json);
    /**
    * Checks for success message.
    **/
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Info");

                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Successfully Registered");
                        Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "Successfully Registered";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();

                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        /**
                         * Removes all the previous data in the SQlite database
                         **/

                        UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                        logout.logoutUser(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(
                                json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),
                                json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),
                                json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),
                                json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),
                                json_user.getString(KEY_ADDRESS1),
                                json_user.getString(KEY_ADDRESS2),
                                json_user.getString(KEY_CITY),
                                json_user.getString(KEY_STATE),
                                json_user.getString(KEY_POSTAL),
                                json_user.getString(KEY_COUNTRY),
                                json_user.getString(KEY_PHONE),
                                json_user.getString(KEY_UID),
                                json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));

                        /**
                         * Stores registered data in SQlite Database
                         * Launch Login Fragment
                         **/                           
                        FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        mFragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE); 
                        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, new LoginFragment(), "Login Fragment");
                        mFragmentTransaction.commit();

                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }

                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==2){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("User already exists");
                    }
                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==3){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Invalid Email id");
                    }

                }

                else{
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
   }

    public void NetAsync(View view){
        new NetCheck().execute();
    }
   }
```

This is the log file:

```
05-06 02:06:03.630: E/ViewRootImpl(22946): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
05-06 02:06:07.510: E/JSON(22946): {"tag":"register","success":0,"error":0,"firstname":null,"lastname":null,"email":"lyndaonn@gmail.com","username":"lynda","password":"asd123","address1":"jalan kematu","address2":"","city":"kering","state":"kerinv","country":"Malaysia","phone":"01326549785"}
{"tag":"register","success":1,"error":0,"firstname":null,"lastname":null,"email":"lyndaonn@gmail.com","username":"lynda","password":"asd123","address1":"jalan kematu","address2":"","city":"kering","state":"kerinv","country":"Malaysia","phone":"01326549785","user":{"fname":"Linda","lname":"Onn","email":"lyndaonn@gmail.com","uname":"lynda","address1":"jalan kematu","address2":"","city":"kering","state":"kerinv","postal":"45678","country":"Malaysia","phone":"01326549785","uid":"5367d30f31d169.01195822","created_at":"2014-05-05 11:06:07"}}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't just dump your whole class file here. Try to recreate your problem with as [little code as possible](http://www.sscce.org/) . Chances are, you will find the answer yourself.

Comment: Why not just set a breakpoint in onPostExecute and see what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

i guess a JSONException is thrown somewhere early in your onPostExecute.  e.printStacktrace() does not neccesarily go to LogCat - better use

```
Log.d("ProcessRegister", "JSONException", e);
```

in

```
catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

 }
```

then you will see what's going on. And as the others mentionend just try to set a breakpoint in your method and step through it, that's probably even easier.